# Sublime Text insert numbers increasing after some selections

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm looking for something that increase numbers like:

```
row| -> row1
row| -> row1

row| -> row2
row| -> row2

row| -> row3
row| -> row3
```

Until now I use [InsertNums](https://github.com/jbrooksuk/InsertNums) and it's so helpful but I don't know... Is there something like 1:1:2 input? initial:step:after_selection.